# PHP script called by cron not terminating

Tags: php, cron

Hej fellows,

I´m trying to run a php script via cron, everything seems to work properly except for the end of my script. It seems that the script is not terminating when it has finished its job, when I log in after the cronjob was called several times the server is extremely slow and the mysql blocks me because of too much connections. The php isn´t exiting, the process is stuck...
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Please explain a little what the code does, if possible, include it, as we cant guess without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are running a resource expensive and/or time consuming query in your PHP script. What could be happening is that the previous query does not finish before your next cron run which makes the machine quickly use up all the available resources causing the server to grind to a halt.

You should look into some kind of a lock-file mechanism which would make sure a new query is executed only if the last one finished successfully.

Comment: Mhm, seems to be neither, I got lots of RAM left and the script "only" takes around 40 minutes to execute, the cron itself is called every 4 houres. In fact the script recieves a bunch of urls of feeds and parses them, after that the items are partly saved into a local mysql database. When I run the script myself (via "php myscript.php") everything seems to work quite well :(